# ErrnoException: statfs failed: EACCES (Permission denied) & Invalid path: /mnt/sdcard

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

My android app uses Samsung SPen SDK 2.2. I have > 50 users and > 3 months I did not get any crash reports, but today I got one in Google Play Developer Console. It came from Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (Android 4.3), but there are a lot of other users with the same device never had this problem.

Do you have any idea of what could be the reason of the crash? I don't even know how to reproduce it on my test device.

The app code does NOT work with SD card (nothing like

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

, no hardcoded paths to /mnt/sdcard, etc.), it does not have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Also, the app cannot be installed/moved to SD card.

The crash report contains the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /mnt/sdcard
at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:46)
at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:39)
at com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView.onDetachedFromWindow(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:13064)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3368)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5959)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:5942)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:378)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:328)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:88)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:159)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: statfs failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.Posix.statfs(Native Method)
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.statfs(ForwardingOs.java:131)
at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:44)
... 27 more
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Hamid, I have no idea which code produced this exception, I have provided all information I can see in Dev Console crash reports.

Comment: post the code portion where you trying to access `ExtertnalStorage`.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but if you read the question again, you will see that I do NOT use this or any other code to access to SD card/internal storage.